# Different UTF-8-Handling of Ext.JSON.encode() and Chrome's JSON.stringify()

Tags: json, extjs, unicode, utf-8

I found a difference between Ext JS's (Version 4.1) `Ext.JSON.encode()` and Chrome's (Version 21.0.1180.79) `JSON.stringify()` when used in Chrome's console:

```
JSON.stringify({"title": "ä"})
> "{"title":"ä"}"

Ext.JSON.encode({"title": "ä"})
> "{"title":"\u00e4"}"
```

Since I want to show the results in the browser, I prefer Chrome's result, but I know that I cannot really rely on Chrome's JSON handling in other browsers. So how can I achieve Chrome's result with Sencha's Ext JS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set Ext.USE_NATIVE_JSON to true in Extjs 4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that the value is the same. *\u00e4* is the real utf-8 representation of the character *ä*. Chrome may output the *ä* decoded for better user expirience, but when decoding, both values are same:

```
JSON.stringify({"title": "ä"})
> "{"title":"ä"}"
Ext.JSON.encode({"title": "ä"})
> "{"title":"\u00e4"}"
JSON.parse('{"title":"ä"}')
> Object {title: "ä"}
Ext.JSON.decode('{"title":"\u00e4"}')
> Object {title: "ä"}
JSON.parse('{"title":"\u00e4"}')
> Object {title: "ä"}
Ext.JSON.decode('{"title":"ä"}')
> Object {title: "ä"}
```